# Return both checked and unchecked checkbox values

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I have a table of checkboxes, and I want to return not only the checked values, but the unchecked as well.

```
function aa(){
        var form1=document.getElementById("form1");
        form1.action="SomeAction.do?flag=doSomething";
            form1.submit();

    }

<form id="form1" method="post" >
<table table class="tg">
        <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="1" /></th>
        <th>111</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="1" /></th>
        <th>222</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="1" /></th>
        <th>333</th>
</table>
</form>
```

I'm accepting the checkbox values with this...

```
String[] nums = request.getParameterValues("selected");
```

I want to get a 1 for every checked, and 0 or null for non-checked.
For example if 1 and 3 are checked, my array would be [1,,3] or [1,0,3]

Comment: Post what code you have written to try and do this, and what problems you are having with it.

Comment: *I want to get a 1 for every checked, and 0 or null for non-checked.* Since HTML checkboxes don't work that way, I bet you're struggling with that. What does this have to do with Java or JSP?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I wrote the code in question in JSP and Java

Comment: Yes, but it's the web browser behavior you want to change. The brand of hammer used to build your home, *probably* doesn't matter when the water main bursts.

Comment: @ScottHunter I wrote the code in question, but so far I only managed to get an array of checked values. so [1,1] for checking 1 and 3, and I would like [1,,1] instead.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'm not sure what you mean. I'm so bad with JS and front-end stuff, but I think there might be a way to achieve this by modifying aa(). Like writing a condition... if unchecked, put a 0 in the array, or something like that...

Comment: *I'm so bad with JS and front-end stuff, but I think there might be a way to achieve this by modifying aa().* And `aa` is a **JavaScript** function. Which is why I asked why you tagged this question as you did. It is a JavaScript question. It is also incomplete. Please edit it into a MCVE. You shouldn't need any Java or JSP to do so. How do you invoke `aa`?

Comment: The current approach assumes the `num` values will be POSTed in a certain order, e.g. the front-end and back-end are tightly coupled.  Consider using a unique name for each element instead of an array.  This simplifies the front-end, and the back-end can interpret a missing POSTed value as 0.